# Why is HingeAngleSensor.GetDefaultAsync always return null even if I have hinge sensor?

Tags: c#, wpf, null, sensors

Based on my intel sensor viewer, my laptop has hinge sensor including the angle data. I need to get the angle and display it using WPF but my code always return null.

I have also read about HingeSensor API of windows but I am new to it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.sensors.hingeanglesensor?view=winrt-18362

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Default();
}

private async void Default()
{
  var getDefaultHinge = await HingeAngleSensor.GetDefaultAsync();
  if (getDefaultHinge != null)
    {
         var defaultHingeAngle = hingeAngleReading.AngleInDegrees;
         angleReading.Content = defaultHingeAngle;
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("no hinge sensor detected");
    }
}
```